# How to set the popUp Panel show at the position of mouse cursor in richFaces

Tags: jsf-2, richfaces

Is there any Attributes to be able to put popup panel show in the position of the mouse cursor in richFaces 4.?

I now think of one solution is to impact on the show event in rich: component (). Show() function, set the location for the popup by javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly handle the showing of a richfaces modal panel through javascript as shown [Here](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/devguide/html/rich_modalPanel.html)

[this js function](http://hartshorne.ca/2006/01/23/javascript_cursor_position/) below will give you the x/y coordinate position of the mouse pointer, the return value of which you can pass as arguments to the `Richfaces.showModalPanel` function

`function getPosition(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    var cursor = {x:0, y:0};
    if (e.pageX || e.pageY) {
        cursor.x = e.pageX;
        cursor.y = e.pageY;
    } 
    else {
        var de = document.documentElement;
        var b = document.body;
        cursor.x = e.clientX + 
            (de.scrollLeft || b.scrollLeft) - (de.clientLeft || 0);
        cursor.y = e.clientY + 
            (de.scrollTop || b.scrollTop) - (de.clientTop || 0);
    }
    return cursor;
}`

so you can have `RichFaces.showModalPanel('panel',{top:getPosition(ev).y,left:getPosition(ev).x})`

Sorry about the hideous javascript.

Comment: Thank you so much about your answer. But unfortunately, I've tried and not success :| Here is my XHTML file:

Comment: No file here. Exactly how/where is it failing? Broken javascript (you can tell from the browser developer console) or the popup still shows up outside of the mouse pointer position

Comment: Oh sorry I was so busy sothat I forget to answer your question. The problem will appear when you use a commandLink, commandButton with Action Method (when you want to render the panel after the method), the page will show 2 popup. Finally I've solved the problem, I will take an demo soon in my wordpress soon :). Thank you about your help :) http://phandanghung.wordpress.com/